# changing logsecond parameter in HADR system

Tags: db2-luw

how can I change the logsecond parameter in an HADR system. as much I could understand, I would need to change the parameter by executing the following command first in primary and then in stand by server:

```
db2 update db cfg for db_name using LOGSECOND The_number_of_file
```

is this correct, please let me know as I have to make some changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is correct. However, in order to take effect, it is necessary to recycle the database (stop: force connection, deactivate; start: connect OR activate)